Text::_() with an alternate language not working
My custom component has a need to render pages in different languages based upon some signals not included in the standard Joomla system. Consequently, I have the following code to trigger a change of language when required:
    $chosenLocale = 'fr-FR';

    $app = Factory::getApplication();
    $lang = Factory::getContainer()->get(LanguageFactoryInterface::class)->createLanguage($chosenLocale, $app->get('debug_lang'));
    $lang->load('com_mycomponent', JPATH_ROOT . '/components/com_mycomponent');
    $app->loadLanguage($lang);

However, despite the Factory::getLanguage() method being deprecated from v4.3 onwards, Text::_() is still utilising this rather than Factory::getApplication()->getLanguage() so when I attempt to translate text, the new language loaded above is dutifully ignored.
Can anybody suggest a way to solve this problem? Two undesirable options come to mind so far:

Update the Text class directly to solve the problem and then add this to my repo and make sure to re-apply changes every time a Joomla update comes out with other changes to the file... Meh

Create my own copy of the Text class that addresses the above issue and then replace all cases of use Joomla\CMS\Language\Text; in my component with use statements for my own Text version... Meh (and this doesn't solve the problem for any text coming from core Joomla code or other components and plugins, though likely not a major problem for my purposes at least)



This depends on whether you actually need to change the system language. If you just need translations in a different language in your component, you should replace Text::_() calls with calls on the language instance:
$translation = $lang->_('SOME_CONSTANT');

If you do need to change the language globally, in addition to loading the language instance into application you also need to set Joomla\CMS\Factory::$language value:
$app->loadLanguage($lang);
Joomla\CMS\Factory::$language = $lang;

This should no longer be needed once Joomla\CMS\Factory::getLanguage() method is removed.
You should also note that setting a new language instance can cause various issues like loaded language files being lost or wrong menu items being loaded.

Thanks @Sharky! For some reason, I had not realised that Factory::$language was public so was just assuming there was no way to influence that at runtime. I will try that out. I think I can live with the caveats you mentioned, but will do plenty of testing to confirm.
